# Swing grouping for GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a GUI which I created using swing. I have various components on this page and a have found the UI to look a bit messy. I have checkboxes, text and drop down menu's to name a few. What I want to do now is to group various components or text together under a title. The below illustrates what I mean.

```
       Login
..................
```

And under the dots I would have my checkboxes/existing components

What I want is to create the sort of header Login and those dots as a separator. How do I do this using Java or a swing component ?

Comment: Use a [`TitledBorder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) on the `JPanel` ..

Comment: For better help and especially if you don't get a decent, consider creating and posting your [mcve] as well as an image of what you're currently getting and what you desire. Also remember that layouts can be effectively *nested* by nesting JPanels, each using its own layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Login class which extends JPanel, then you can put the header stuff inside that Login class, give the main frame a BorderLayout and add a Login instance to the NORTH of the BorderLayout, then you can add another Panel in the CENTER of the BorderLayout and change the content of the CENTER panel through the Login class.